# Google App-Script call functions from service

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth

When accessing functions on google appScript from java code using a service account i get an error of:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
  "status" : "INTERNAL"
}
```

The same this happens from app-engine with default credentials

Comment: Are you using the Execution API?

Comment: yes:        ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest().setDevMode(false)
                .setFunction("getSQLLateBucketCollectionStats");

        Operation op = script.scripts().run(AppScriptFactory.TEST_KEY, request).execute();